# I have two tables, one contain students id and couse . the second contain couses , date and time

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one contain students id and couse . the second contain couses , date and time. now i want get the number of student that there couse appear on the second table with the same date and time

Table 1

`Student ID           Cousecode

student 1              Couse A
student 1              Couse B
student 1              Couse C
student 1              Couse D
student 1              Couse E
student 1              Couse F
student 1              Couse G
student 2              Couse A
student 2              Couse B
student 2              Couse C
student 2              Couse D
student 2              Couse E

student 2              Couse F`

> Table 2

```
`Cousecode        date         time
 Couse A        2015-05-04    Mor
```

`
so I want run a query that will loop through table 1 and table 2 to count the number of student that are register for **couse A** since the course appear on table 2

i have run this query 
`SELECT table1.student_id, table1.CourseCode,table2.* FROM  table1 RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.CourseCode = table2.cousecode  WHERE table1.CourseCode = 'Couse B' AND table2.date='2015-05-04' AND table2.time='Mor';`

    but is not working

Comment: You want the number of students against a course? Or something else ...

Answer (score 0):

So, just to make some things clear. The relation between Course and Student is MTM(many to many) hence you need a third table(associative entity) where it only includes pk of student table and pk of course table. Both of them has to be primary key in this third table(and of course foreign keys). When you have done this you want to count the amount of student in a specific course

```
SELECT COUNT(studentID) AS Students_in_course FROM your_table
WHERE courseID=2;
```